# Javascript Posting Multiple File Images not working

Tags: javascript, api, form-data

Below code is for posting multiple images to server. Its showing bad request also if i print the "FormData" its showing only one image

```
 uploadCategoryImages = () => {
 let fileSelect = document.getElementById('contained-button-file');
 let files = fileSelect.files;
 let file;
 let formData = new FormData()
 for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) 
 {
 file = files[i];
 formData.append('photos[]', file, file.name);
 }
 api.post('/api/v1/addimage/category/3', formData)
 .then(function (response) {
 console.log(response)        
 })
 .catch(function (error) {
 alert(error)
 })
 }
```